# Newbie on Flask Python, how to host python app inside an already Apache2 domain web site?

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi, user-permissions

I have searched everywhere in Google and tried many ideas... still to no avail.

Basically I already got an existing Apache2 domain-ed web site hosted in CentOS7 running under its designated **user/group=app_user**. Now I wish to put my flask python (v3.6.5) app called "marketing" inside the web site root. All things already setup and using wsgi which I added into the httpd.conf file below. I tested the python app, ran OK using python3.

I also set the chmod -R 777 (temporarily) and chown -R app_user:app_user.

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:80>
    ServerName xyz.com
    ServerAlias www.xyz.com
    WSGIDaemonProcess marketing user=app_user group=app_user threads=2
    WSGIScriptAlias /marketing /home/myapp/public_html/marketing
    <Directory /home/myapp/public_html/marketing>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

```
### app.py

from flask import Flask
import os

# create an instance of flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 80))
    app.run(host='192.168.0.1', port=port, debug=True)
```

```
### wsgi.py

import sys
import site

site.addsitedir(' /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages')

sys.path.insert(0, ' /home/myapp/public_html/marketing')
```

When I hit the url [www.xyz.com/marketing](http://www.xyz.com/marketing) on a browser... I kept getting error

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /marketing/ on this server.
```

Any idea where I missed?

Reason why I wanna put the python app inside a web site is I dont wish to register another domain name just for the python.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Phew! This time ChatGPT couldnt help much. After days of searching in Google, finally found an angel presented the exact-accurate steps to setup Flask Python on Apache2 server. TQ ye al for reading.